# jquery click on div in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe one of you can help me.
How do I click on a div, by using the Chrome Console?

I want to be able to click the div on this site any ideas.

example: https://gleam.io/ZyYPU/100-subscriber-giveaway-100-usd

Tried this without any luck.

```
$('.entry-method #em2690957').click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select `a` tag and click

```
$('#em2690957').children('a').click();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can this:

```
$('.entry-method, #em2690957').click();
```

Comment: Why should the OP use a `,` selector instead of a descendant selector?

Comment: not a descendant selector. for two different selector

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it via angular:

```
angular.element('#em2690957 a').triggerHandler('click');
```